# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

Please help me out, I have written entire connection string in separate Class "DbConnection"
my code :

public void binddropdownlist()
        {

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

         DbConnection b = new DbConnection();     

        try
        {

            b.OpenConnection();


            string SqlStatement = "Select Col1 + Col2  from tablename";

           SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SqlStatement, b);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter ();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                Locdrplist.DataSource = dt;
                Locdrplist.DataTextField = "Col1";
                Locdrplist.DataValueField = "Col2";
                Locdrplist.DataBind();
            }

        }

        catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "FetchError";

            throw new Exception("error");
        }

        finally
        {
           b.CloseConnection();
        }    
      }
```

I am getting error to pass string value but don't know how to make class instance as string please help me

Comment: Any time you are "getting error" it is pretty important to **show us the error**.

Comment: Can you show us your `DbConnection class`? Also, I assume that query is just for an example, but if it were real, that'd result in an additional error when trying to set the `DataText` and `Value Fields` for your `Locdrplist DropDownList`, because those specified `columns` don't exists in the query result, your select returns 1 `anonymous column`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check DBConnection

```
DbConnection b = new DbConnection();
```

This is not a type of SqlConnection.

The signature of SqlCommand's constructor is:

```
public SqlCommand(string query, SqlConnection conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of teaching, I just wanted to throw this out there. When using these ADO.NET objects, here is the recommended approach to ensure they are properly disposed:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    c.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @PersonID", c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", personId);

        using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (r.Read())
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, clearly the code would have to be fit into your needs, but I'm trying to give you an *overall* example. The `using` statements ensure that `Dispose` is called on all of the objects. This is *very important.* Notice that the command is parameterized, *this is also very important* because it doesn't leave you open to SQL Injection. And finally, when reading data, you can use the `SqlDataReader` for extremely fast and efficient memory usage.

You don't have to use the `SqlDataReader`, you could do something like this:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @PersonID", c))
{
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", personId);

    var dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
}
```